# Camel route not continuing after single choice().when()

Tags: apache-camel

I have a route that looks like this:

```
from(getEndpoint())
    .id(endpoint)
    .filter(notDeleted)
    .process(get)
    .filter(exists)
    .choice()
        .when(hasProperty)
            .wireTap("direct:" + AlternateRoute.ENDPOINT)
    .end()
    .log("Got here")
    .process(postProcessor)
    .bean(dao, "save")
.end();
```

I've tried a few different combinations of `end()` and `endChoice()` but no matter what I do nothing after the `.choice()`/`.wireTap()` seems to run. I don't see the `"Got here"` line logged and I don't see my `postProcessor` or `dao` get hit.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: wireTap cannot be used alone; it has to be used in addition to the regular destination.

Answer (score 0):

Choices are weird in apache camel when you are using java DSL.

Try to simplify your route processing the property in another route:

```
from(getEndpoint())
    .id(endpoint)
    .filter(notDeleted)
    .process(get)
    .filter(exists)
    .wireTap("direct:" + AlternateRoute.ENDPOINT)
    .log("Got here")
    .process(postProcessor)
    .bean(dao, "save")
.end();

from("direct:" + AlternateRoute.ENDPOINT)
    .choice()
        .when(hasProperty)
            .log("Do something")
        .endchoice();
```